# setTimeout causes TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a small phone book web page with React and when a person is either added or person's info is updated I want a small notification to show on the page. I'm doing this by using React hooks in order to give state to variables message and errorMessage.

After an update, the message in question receives its content (e.g. "New contact added") and `setTimeout(() => {setMessage('')}, 6000)` is used to clear the message.

I've tried to search every thread I've found with the key words "TypeError, setTimeout" etc. with no results. I don't even understand what is the problem. I'f I remove the setTimeout altogether everything works fine (the message won't disappear).

Code bellow isn't the code I use but it does contain the same exact problem, namely setTimeout causes TypeError. There is no update of contacts, we just try to change the state of the message with setTimeout.

```
import React, {useState, setTimeout} from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    //Setting up message
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    //Change the state of message to Testing after 6 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {setMessage("Testing")}, 6000)
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you importing setTimeout from React?

Comment: setTimeout needs a function and a timer but you are using an object instead of a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` comes with a `JavaScript` and **NOT** from `React`,

As you imported `setTimeout` from `react`, you are getting this error,

```
import React, {useState, setTimeout} from 'react';
```

just remove `setTimeout` from import like,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `setTimeout` from React, that's the issue. Just remove it from the import, and you will be fine since its a native javascript method.

Also, try to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) when you are making these kinds of changes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  useEffect(() => {
     const timeout = setTimeout(() => {setMessage("Testing")}, 6000)
     return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
     }

  });
```

This avoids setting up timeout every time component is rendered and clears it when unmounted.